# Table Indexing on PostgreSQL for performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I am solving performance issues on PostgreSQL and I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE main_transaction (
   id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('main_transaction_id_seq'::regclass),
   description character varying(255) NOT NULL,
   request_no character varying(18),
   account character varying(50),
   ....
 )
```

Above table has 34 columns including 3 `FOREIGN KEY`s and it has over 1 Million rows data. I have the following conditional `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM main_transaction
WHERE upper(request_no) LIKE upper(concat('%','20080417-0258-0697','%'))
```

Returning the result in over 2 seconds. I want to decrease working time by using table indexing. So far, I have used `btree` indexing. However, I didn't notice any fast result. My question is, how can I improve performance for above query?

Comment: Why the `%`? the search string already has the maximum length for the column...

Comment: ('%','20080417-0258-0697','%') -> (('%',:field,'%') )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only chance to search for a pattern that begins with `%` is a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON main_transaction
   USING gin (upper(request_no) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: Great!  I also have foreign keys in my table and I am using CROSS JOIN to link the tables by id and it is causing slow performance. I have a `profile_id` column in `main_transaction` table for `profile` table and in profile table I have `customer_id` for `customer` table.   

`SELECT * FROM main_transaction t
CROSS JOIN main_profile p
CROSS JOIN main_customer c 
WHERE t.profile_id = p.id
AND p.user_id = c.id
AND (
 upper(t.request_no) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12 ','%'))
 OR upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6  12','%'))
)`.  Thank you

Comment: Well, then open a question for it.

Comment: here is the url :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942061/postgresql-cross-join-indexing-for-performance