# PostgreSQL CROSS JOIN indexing for performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

This is the second part of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938650/table-indexing-on-postgresql-for-performance). 
So I have the following table,

```
CREATE TABLE public.main_transaction
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('main_transaction_id_seq'::regclass),
  profile_id integer NOT NULL,
  request_no character varying(18),
  user_id bigint,
  .....
  CONSTRAINT main_transaction_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_main_transaction_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES public.jhi_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
      REFERENCES public.main_profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,

  CONSTRAINT main_transaction_profile_id_20_fk_main_profile_id FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
      REFERENCES public.main_profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
)
```

In the table I have foreign keys in my table and I am using `CROSS JOIN` to link the tables by **id** and it is causing slow performance( returning result in **12 secs** for over 1 Million row data).
More precisely,I have a `profile_id` column in **main_transaction(above)** table for **profile** table and in **profile** table I have `customer_id` for **customer** table. So, my query is as following,

```
SELECT * FROM main_transaction t 
CROSS JOIN main_profile p 
CROSS JOIN main_customer c 
WHERE t.profile_id = p.id
AND p.user_id = c.id 
AND ( upper(t.request_no) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12 ','%')) 
      OR upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12','%')) 
)
```

If you need structure of `profile` and `customer` table, I can comment.

Explain:

```
"Merge Join  (cost=27220.51..266464.85 rows=218 width=1692) (actual time=9399.370..9399.370 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Merge Cond: (t.profile_id = p.id)"
"  Join Filter: ((upper((t.request_no)::text) ~~ upper(concat('%', ' 0-90-6 12 ', '%'))) OR (upper((c.phone)::text) ~~ upper(concat('%', ' 0-90-6 12, '%'))))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1089489"
"  Buffers: shared hit=453158 read=413372, temp read=1560 written=1560"
"  ->  Index Scan using main_transaction_profile_id_idx on main_transaction t  (cost=0.43..198177.36 rows=1089489 width=1455) (actual time=0.004..3913.501 rows=1089489 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=393656 read=410718"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=27218.84..27645.70 rows=85372 width=237) (actual time=165.565..239.572 rows=1133650 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=59502 read=2654, temp read=1560 written=1560"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=27218.84..27432.27 rows=85372 width=237) (actual time=165.560..188.746 rows=85368 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: p.id"
"              Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 12480kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=59502 read=2654, temp read=1560 written=1560"
"              ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.73..10594.24 rows=85372 width=237) (actual time=0.007..96.133 rows=85372 loops=1)"
"                    Merge Cond: (p.user_id = c.id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=59502 read=2654"
"                    ->  Index Scan using main_profile_e8701ad4 on main_profile p  (cost=0.29..3350.82 rows=85372 width=40) (actual time=0.003..24.892 rows=85372 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=29016 read=963"
"                    ->  Index Scan using main_customer_pkey on main_customer c  (cost=0.29..5963.16 rows=85506 width=197) (actual time=0.003..34.235 rows=85506 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=30486 read=1691"
"Planning time: 0.850 ms"
"Execution time: 9407.244 ms"
```

Comment: First: don't write `CROSS JOIN` when you actually want `INNER JOIN`. Second: Do you have indexes on the origin of the foreign keys? Third: Please show the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. Edit the question to add that information.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe 
First: OK, will do it. 
Second:  For `profile` table, I only have `btree` index on `user_id`.  And for `customer` table I have `gin` index for `phone`.
Third:  Will add it to the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I changed query to INNER JOIN However didn't notice any performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the `OR` — you can never get decent performance as long as you have an `OR` like this in your `WHERE` clause.

Rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM main_transaction t 
   JOIN main_profile p ON t.profile_id = p.id
   JOIN main_customer c ON p.user_id = c.id 
WHERE upper(t.request_no) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12 ','%'))
UNION
SELECT * FROM main_transaction t 
   JOIN main_profile p ON t.profile_id = p.id
   JOIN main_customer c ON p.user_id = c.id 
WHERE upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12','%'));
```

Then make sure you have the following indexes (apart from the indexes on the `id`s):

```
CREATE INDEX ON main_transaction (profile_id);
CREATE INDEX ON main_transaction USING gin (upper(request_no) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON main_profile (user_id);
CREATE INDEX ON main_customer USING gin (upper(phone) gin_trgm_ops);
```

That should make a difference.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM main_transaction t
JOIN main_profile p ON (t.profile_id = p.id)
JOIN main_customer c ON (p.user_id = c.id)
WHERE 
(
 upper(t.request_no) LIKE upper(concat('%','0-90-6 12 ','%'))
        OR upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%''0-90-6 12 ','%')) 
)`
I created indexes, however no better performance. What else can you suggest, If you need more detailed info, please write

Comment: @mr.sanatbek First: remove all thes silly `upper()`s. they do nothing, exept making indexes unusable and things slower. And the OR list (on othogonal conditions) is a disaster, IMHO

Comment: @joop inside `upper()` there can be letter(it is variable). Sorry for my silly example

Comment: The literal `'0-90-6 12 '` does not contain any letter, so the upper is a no-op.

Comment: @joop Maybe the example was just badly chosen. Case insensitive search is not an unusual requirement.

Comment: IMHO questions with *badly chosen* examples don't deserve answers. And neither do questions with badly chosen syntax ... (The cross join is hilarious, IMHO, especially in combination with *does not perform* )

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you please checkout this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252549/postgresql-table-indexing