# PostgreSQL table indexing

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing

I want to index my tables for the following query:

```
select 
    t.*
from main_transaction t 
left join main_profile profile on profile.id = t.profile_id
left join main_customer customer on (customer.id = profile.user_id) 
where
(upper(t.request_no) like upper(('%'||@requestNumber||'%')) or OR upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%',||@phoneNumber||,'%')))
 and t.service_type = 'SERVICE_1'
 and t.status  = 'SUCCESS'
 and t.mode = 'AUTO'
 and t.transaction_type = 'WITHDRAW'
 and customer.client = 'corp'
 and t.pub_date>='2018-09-05' and t.pub_date<='2018-11-05'
order by t.pub_date desc, t.id asc 
LIMIT 1000;
```

This is how I tried to index my tables:

```
CREATE INDEX main_transaction_pr_id ON main_transaction (profile_id);
CREATE INDEX main_profile_user_id ON main_profile (user_id);
CREATE INDEX main_customer_client ON main_customer (client);
CREATE INDEX main_transaction_gin_req_no ON main_transaction USING gin (upper(request_no) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX main_customer_gin_phone ON main_customer USING gin (upper(phone) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX main_transaction_general ON main_transaction (service_type, status, mode, transaction_type); --> don't know if this one is true!!
```

After indexing like above my query is spending over 4.5 seconds for just selecting 1000 rows!

I am selecting from the following table which has 34 columns including 3 FOREIGN KEYs and it has over 3 million data rows:

```
CREATE TABLE main_transaction (
   id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('main_transaction_id_seq'::regclass),
   description character varying(255) NOT NULL,
   request_no character varying(18),
   account character varying(50),
   service_type character varying(50),
   pub_date" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL,
   "service_id" varchar(50) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
   ....
 );
```

I am also joining two tables (`main_profile`, `main_customer`) for searching `customer.phone` and for selecting `customer.client`. To get to the `main_customer` table from `main_transaction` table, I can only go by `main_profile`

My question is how can I index my table too increase performance for above query?

Please, do not use `UNION` for `OR` for this case `(upper(t.request_no) like upper(('%'||@requestNumber||'%')) or OR upper(c.phone) LIKE upper(concat('%',||@phoneNumber||,'%')))` instead can we use `case when` condition? Because, I have to convert my PostgreSQL query into Hibernate JPA! And I don't know how to convert `UNION` except `Hibernate - Native SQL` which I am not allowed to use.

Explain:

```
Limit  (cost=411601.73..411601.82 rows=38 width=1906) (actual time=3885.380..3885.381 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=411601.73..411601.82 rows=38 width=1906) (actual time=3885.380..3885.380 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: t.pub_date DESC, t.id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=20817.10..411600.73 rows=38 width=1906) (actual time=3214.473..3885.369 rows=1 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (t.profile_id = profile.id)
              Join Filter: ((upper((t.request_no)::text) ~~ '%20181104-2158-2723948%'::text) OR (upper((customer.phone)::text) ~~ '%20181104-2158-2723948%'::text))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 593118
              ->  Seq Scan on main_transaction t  (cost=0.00..288212.28 rows=205572 width=1906) (actual time=0.068..1527.677 rows=593119 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((pub_date >= '2016-09-05 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (pub_date <= '2018-11-05 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((service_type)::text = 'SERVICE_1'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'SUCCESS'::text) AND ((mode)::text = 'AUTO'::text) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'WITHDRAW'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2132732
              ->  Hash  (cost=17670.80..17670.80 rows=180984 width=16) (actual time=211.211..211.211 rows=181516 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 131072  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3166kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=6936.09..17670.80 rows=180984 width=16) (actual time=46.846..183.689 rows=181516 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (customer.id = profile.user_id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on main_customer customer  (cost=0.00..5699.73 rows=181106 width=16) (actual time=0.013..40.866 rows=181618 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((client)::text = 'corp'::text)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 16920
                          ->  Hash  (cost=3680.04..3680.04 rows=198404 width=8) (actual time=46.087..46.087 rows=198404 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 131072  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 2966kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on main_profile profile  (cost=0.00..3680.04 rows=198404 width=8) (actual time=0.008..20.099 rows=198404 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.757 ms
Execution time: 3885.680 ms
```

Comment: Because you are using `*` and the postgresql choose `seq scan`, Just take what column do you need. And see again plan execution what postgresql do..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 1):

With the restriction to not use `UNION`, you won't get a good plan.

You can slightly speed up processing with the following indexes:

```
main_transaction ((service_type::text), (status::text), (mode::text),
                  (transaction_type::text), pub_date)
main_customer ((client::text))
```

These should at least get rid of the sequential scans, but the hash join that takes the lion's share of the processing time will remain.