# PostgreSQL: Performance increasing on SELECT query for timestamp with time zone column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I have more than 1 million rows in the table and my `SELECT` query is slow when I search between *date range* . 
So, I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.main_transaction
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('main_transaction_id_seq'::regclass),
  description character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  transaction_type character varying(18) NOT NULL,
  pub_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

Above table has 34 columns including 3 `FOREIGN KEY`s and
I want to speed up the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM main_transaction 
WHERE 
   pub_date >= '2018-01-01'
   AND pub_date <'2018-01-08'
```

Now, it is working in **12 secs**. :(

By the way, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320455/postgresql-speed-up-select-query-in-table-with-millions-of-rows/45321419#45321419) solution. However, I didn't notice much change.

execution plan:

```
Seq Scan on main_transaction t (cost=0.00..74437.33 rows=28974 width=1455)
  Filter: ((pub_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (pub_date < '2018-01-08 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone))
```

Comment: execution plan please

Comment: What index definition do you have?

Comment: @Vao Tsun "Seq Scan on main_transaction t  (cost=0.00..74437.33 rows=28974 width=1455)"
"  Filter: ((pub_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (pub_date < '2018-01-08 00:00:00+05'::timestamp with time zone))"

Comment: @Ben Please refer to the following links to understand my table [1-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942061/postgresql-cross-join-indexing-for-performance) and [2-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938650/table-indexing-on-postgresql-for-performance)

Comment: Laurenz suggests creating index in your refered answer - what you mean it did not help? how you checked that? analyzed table and checked the plan?..

Comment: Performance is the same, after indexing as @Laurenz said.

Comment: Please put the relevant information into this question.

Comment: @Ben Please can you clarify what do you mean by relevant? And, what is irrelevant in my question.

Comment: Please put the needed information in the question. E.g. the index definitions.

Comment: @ben Please open 1-link and 2-link as I mentioned above comment. There are explained all Constraints and index definitions. Laurenz helped me to do my indexing before. So, no more indexes defined except those links.

Comment: Please put the information required for **this** question into **this** question. That's how this site is supposed to work.